# How to clip textures when drawing?

Tags: xna

How do i draw a texture2D in a specific area (rectangle) where the texture is bigger than the rectangle, and i dont want to draw outside the rectangle. So that means i want to cut the texture so it fits the rectangle area (if its too big).

For example if the rectangle area is 200 x 100 and my texture (the smiley) is 200 x 150
then i want to cut the last 50 off so it only draws 200 x 100

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SpriteBatch.Draw(Texture2D, Rectangle, Nullable<Rectangle>, Color)`

```
public void Draw (
         Texture2D texture,
         Rectangle destinationRectangle,
         Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
         Color color
)
```

compare the size of the `destinationRectangle` and the size of the `texture`. Next you need to take the lowest values ​​and using them in `sourceRectangle`